# Projective Jacobian matrix and determinant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if there is an interpretation of the projective Jacobian matrix in algebraic geometry. In affine space, this matrix represents the linear map on tangent spaces induced by a function. But if projective space, if $F$ if a endomorphism on, say, $P^2$, what geometrically would the Jacobian matrix represent? It is a 3 by 3 matrix. Is there some sort of natural "projective tangent space at a point"?

Supposing this was some sort of notion, then things still do not exactly behave as I would expect them to. For example, in the affine case, if F is an endomorphism on $A^n$, then the Jacobian determinant is zero at a point if and only if there is ramification at that point (and I believe this is regardless of characteristic). And, while it seems like this may be the case in characteristic 0, it is not in finite characteristics. The map $[yz:zx:xy]$ is a birational automorphism, but in fields of characteristic 2, its Jacobian determinat is identically $0$.

So does anyone know much about this, or know where I can find out more? The Jacobian determinant of a projective automorphism has been very useful to me in my research, and while I do not need to learn anything specifically, it would be nice to understand this tool I am using much more than I do now.